# Cual es la traduccion correcta de "Due date" y "completion date"?

Tags: traducción

When submitting files:
Due Date
Dec 1 2018

completion date:
Nov 23 2018

So, Due date is maximum date limit, and completion date is when you completed the task.

---

Para mi "due date" es "fecha limite"

Y "completion date" es "fecha de entrega"

pero, es esta traduccion correcta?

Comment: Favor @luisluix puede dar ejemplos, en inglés, en los cuales se usen esas expresiones?

Comment: @alvalongo agregue mas contexto.

Comment: Those two seem the most accurate translations to me. Congrats.

Comment: "Fecha límite" is definitely what I'm used to.  Your proposed "fecha de entrega" sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para *Due date* hay varias alternativas que se pueden usar. La que ofreces en la pregunta es una de ellas pero también se puede usar **término**, **plazo** o **fecha tope**.

En cuanto a **fecha de entrega**, no es tan simple. Dependiendo del contexto tambien se puede referir al plazo (due date en inglés).

> La **fecha de entrega** para la tarea de matemáticas es el próximo jueves.

Sin embargo, sí se puede usar **fecha de entrega** para hacer referencia a la fecha en que, de hecho, se entregó alguna cosa como por ejemplo una tarea, un proyecto, un paquete, etc.

> La **fecha de entrega** del paquete fue al pasado miércoles.

Pero para complicar las cosas, si el locutor esta utilizando un tono irónico, tendremos algo como lo siguiente.

> Lo siento, no puedo recibir su documento, la **fecha de entrega** fue el pasado miércoles.

Otras alternativas para *completion date* pueden ser **fecha de finalización**, **fecha de culminación**, **fecha de término** (observa que la palabra término sola significa *due date* como lo mencioné arriba), **fecha de cumplimiento**.

Finalmente, si quieres ser más claro (en el caso de *completion date*) te sugiero que consideres el uso la forma verbal. Por ejemplo, en lugar de:

> La **fecha de conclusión** del proyecto fue el 25 de mayo.

Puedes usar:

> El proyecto se **concluyó** el 25 de mayo.